# How to grab Url with Xpath

Tags: php, laravel, xpath, domparser

The question is how to grab url which is in `div class`. And in `ul` tag like below. But just the first `<li>` becouse second li has another URL that i dont want?

```
<div class="p-articlelist-content-right">
    <ul class="p-articlelist-content-btn clearfix">
        <li><a href="https://sumai.tokyu-land.co.jp/branz/yuhigaoka-41/"
```

I tried this but no effects.

```
$cNames = $xpath->query("//div[@class='p-articlelist-content-right']/li/");
```

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"//div[@class='p-articlelist-content-right'][1][1]"

or

"//ul[@class='p-articlelist-content-btn clearfix'][1]"

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to var_dump it, shows me this `["length"]=>
  int(1)` How can I see inside that array? Do I have link or not. And there 9 URL not just one. that means I cant get next URL?